# Angular 4 set property from another class

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have 2 class like as:

```
UserInfo

export class UserInfo {
    id: number;
    fullName: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    address: string;
    dob: string
}
```

User

```
import {UserInfo} from './User-Info'

export class User {
    id: number;
    userName: String;
    status: String;
    userInfo: UserInfo;

    constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string, address: string){
        this.userInfo.firstName = firstName;
        this.userInfo.lastName = lastName;
        this.userInfo.address = address;
      }
```

}
I'm using the FormGroup to set data value:

```
let user: User = new User(
    this.userForm.controls['firstName'].value,
    this.userForm.controls['lastName'].value,
    this.userForm.controls['address'].value);
this.userService.createUser(user);
```

I debug on a browser: the value of form can get successful but when creating new User, I have an error message:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'firstName' of undefined
    at new User (User.ts:10)
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to initlize your `userInfo` variable something like

```
userInfo:UserInfo = new UserInfo();
```

or in constructor

```
constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string, address: string) {
    this.userInfor=new UserInfo();

    this.userInfo.firstName = firstName;
    this.userInfo.lastName = lastName;
    this.userInfo.address = address;
}
```

Comment: thats correct. typescript compiler watch model as empty/undefined and because of that you have to initialize it.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's amazing